# Synchronize two different JMeter programs into one or import thread group from different program

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have created one program in JMeter using Blazemeter.

I want to synchronize another JMeter program into this.

Just like Java programs, I want to import file /class and use it to here

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [Include Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) to include in your program,

Before that in the included jmx:

> The include controller is designed to use an external JMX file. To use it, create a Test Fragment underneath the Test Plan and add any desired samplers, controllers etc. below it. Then save the Test Plan.

Another option is built in [merge](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-test-plan.html#load_save) command under the File menu.